# Minimum size integer accommodating some divisors within some prescribed gaps

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-progression

Assume we pick $t$ uniformly random integers $l_1$ to $l_t$ independently from $1$ to $2^v$.

Assume $k_1$ through $k_t$ are similarly picked from $1$ to $2^r$.

> What is the minimum size of non-negative integer $a$ such that at every $i$ from $1$ to $t$ we have $k_i|(a-l_i)$?

Comment: I think by CRT it is $\prod_{i=1}^t k_i$ size at most.

Comment: I just was going to write that. But the upper limit is true when $k_i$ are mutually co-prime. If $(k_i,k_j)=x$ and $x \nmid (l_i-l_j)$ for any two $i,j$, then there won't exist any such $a$.